# Sum values based on date compared to current date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, spreadsheet, excel-365

I am currently trying to create an if statement that sums values based on whether a date has passed.

[Excel example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAK0F.png)

M1 to M12 dictate the months of the year e.g. 01/01/2021 for M1 and 01/12/2021 for M12

Now I want to create or use a formula that sums the values in row 4 based on what month we are currently in --> If we are currently in M1, e.g. 15/01/2021, then it only needs to sum the value in A4. However, if we are, for example, in M3 (28/03/2021) then it needs to sum A4 + B4 + C4

I tried using the following formula but the problem is that when it finds a value larger than 01/01/2021 it doesn't take other months into consideration anymore

```
=IF(TODAY()>=A2;A4;IF(TODAY()>=B2;SUM(A4:B4);0))
```

I added the zero at the end of the function to close the formula but my idea was to prolong it up til 12 months. However, it only ever sums the first cell (A4) because conditions have already been met. How do I 'overwrite' the first condition if more months have passed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated; I excuse myself for asking potentially dumb questions but Excel isn't my strong point and I am trying to learn.

Kind regards,

VHes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUM(INDEX(4:4,SEQUENCE(MONTH(TODAY()))))
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! This works perfectly. Now I'm going to try and figure out how exactly this does work haha! Saved my day!

Comment: Evidently @ForwardEd, with changing data that would be a must =)

Comment: I already figured this out, but thanks for the headsup!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach using SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(A2:L2,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),0),A4:L4)
```

If SEQUENCE is not supported by your version of excel, (based on comments it does), you could also try the following:

```
=SUM(A4:INDEX(A4:L4,MONTH(TODAY())))
```

The trick here is that INDEX actually supplies a cell address, and displays the contents of that cell when needed.

[image: POC]

Comment: @Forward Ed 

Thanks man! I will actually have to use this once I swap pc's I think. I tried your solution as well now and it works great too! Much appreciated buddy! :)